# how to clip a hole in a canvas using onmousedown while following the mouse path

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Goals:

1. display a background image masked by a canvas all inside a div
2. onmousedown and onmousemove: unmask a circular portion of that background image, centered on the mouse pointer.
3. Return to a complete mask onmouseup

Here's what I have so far - any help would be appreciated. It seems to work ok, but it leaves the trace of where the mouse has been. I'd like it to only show the circular area surrounding where the mouse immediately is at any given point.

functional JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shaedmorgan/4325d8pg/19/

I've tried changing the globalCompositeOperation, and using clip(), but I can't seem to get it right. I think the main issue lies in the "redraw" function. Thanks for taking a look.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

window.onload = function () {
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
let centerx = canvas.width/2;
let centery = canvas.height/2;
let radius = 100;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
}

function getMouse(e, canvas) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: (e.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
    y: (e.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
  };
}

function redraw (canvas, mouse) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc((canvas.width) / 2, (canvas.height) / 2, (canvas.width) / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, (canvas.width) / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill('evenodd'); 
}

function moveOnMouseDown (canvas, moveFunction) {
  var endMove = function () {
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;
    let centerx = canvas.width/2;
    let centery = canvas.height/2;
    let radius = 100;

    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveFunction);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', endMove);
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var mouse = getMouse(event,canvas)
    redraw(canvas,mouse)
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveFunction);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', endMove);
  });
}

moveOnMouseDown(document.getElementById('canvas'), function (e) {
  var mouse = getMouse(e, document.getElementById('canvas'));
  //console.log(mouse) <--confirmed mouse position is good.
  redraw(document.getElementById('canvas'), mouse);
})
```

```css
#TML_div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='TML_div'>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

```css
#TML_div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id='TML_div'>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Try resetting the canvas in the `redraw` function: https://jsfiddle.net/7afezpxL/

Comment: @sol this does it! any ideas how to overlay this on a background image? I've tried adding the image with <img src=imagesrcURL> but it breaks the code (which is why I didn't include it in the original post.

Edit: Also - if you post this as an answer, I'm happy to accept it :)

Comment: Seems to work as a background image: https://jsfiddle.net/t1gzsj7k/

Comment: This hits all of the goals. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset the canvas in the redraw function:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

window.onload = function() {
  drawCircle();
}

function clearCanvas() {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawCircle() {
  canvas.width = 200;
  canvas.height = 200;
  let centerx = canvas.width / 2;
  let centery = canvas.height / 2;
  let radius = 100;

  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function getMouse(e, canvas) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: (e.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - rect.left) * canvas.width,
    y: (e.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - rect.top) * canvas.height
  };
}

function redraw(canvas, mouse) {
  clearCanvas();
  drawCircle();

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in'
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc((canvas.width) / 2, (canvas.height) / 2, (canvas.width) / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, (canvas.width) / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill('evenodd');

}

function moveOnMouseDown(canvas, moveFunction) {
  var endMove = function() {
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;
    let centerx = canvas.width / 2;
    let centery = canvas.height / 2;
    let radius = 100;

    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerx, centery, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveFunction);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', endMove);
  };

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    var mouse = getMouse(event, canvas)
    redraw(canvas, mouse)
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveFunction);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', endMove);
  });
}

moveOnMouseDown(document.getElementById('canvas'), function(e) {
  var mouse = getMouse(e, document.getElementById('canvas'));
  //console.log(mouse) <--confirmed mouse position is good.
  redraw(document.getElementById('canvas'), mouse);
})
```

```css
#TML_div {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
}
```

```html
<div id='TML_div'>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```